# What is the difference bettween numpy.mod() and numpy.remainder()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([10,20,30]) 
b = np.array([3,5,7]) 

print(np.mod(a,b))
```

Output:

> [1 0 2]

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([10,20,30]) 
b = np.array([3,5,7]) 

print(np.remainder(a,b))
```

Output:

> [1 0 2]

Both functions gave the same value, are there any differences?

Answer (score 9):

No difference, they are aliases:

```
>>> np.mod is np.remainder
True
```

Specifically, mod is alias for remainder:

```
>>> np.mod.__name__
'remainder'
```

Comment: I am a beginner at numPy, I would like to know, Is there any specific reason behind it to have two functions like that which does the exact same thing?

Just curious!!!, It will definitely help me understand better...

Comment: googling this doesn't give very clear results. undocumented... until now :)

Comment: Couple of confused comments [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9702#issuecomment-330133068).